# Default SHORT description in woocommerce product pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I would like to add a default line in all the woocommerce product short description forms,  something like "free local shipping". It will be great if this line line in the short description can be edited or removed everytime a new product is being edited. Can someone please let me know how if you know the way to get this done.  Thank you for your help in advance.

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to achive you taarget and have the ability to change the Text area in case we need to display different massage other than the default in the product page we need to do three steps:

**Step 1: Add Text Area to Product General Tab in the admin panel**

```
// Display Text in Admin Panel 
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'product_custom_text_area');

function product_custom_text_area()
{

    // Custom Product Text Area

    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
        array(
        'id'          => '_optional_textarea',
        'label'       => __('Optional Text Area', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => 'Product Text',
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'description' => __('This Text will be Displayed in Product Short Desc', 'woocommerce')
        )
    );
}
```

**Step 2: Save The Text in our Database in case we added text**

```
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'product_custom_text_area_save');

function product_custom_text_area_save($post_id)
{
    if (!empty($_POST['_optional_textarea'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_optional_textarea', esc_attr($_POST['_optional_textarea']));
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Display our text in product page if exist if not display our Default message**

```
//Display The Text in Product Page

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_text_area');

function display_text_area()
{
    global $post;
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, '_optional_textarea', true)) {
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_optional_textarea', true);
        return;
    }

    echo __('FREE LOCAL SHIPPING', 'woocommerce');
}
```

**Default Output**

[image: Default Output]

**BackEnd**

[image]

> if you want to display only Default hardcoded text in the short description you need to use only this function:

```
//Display The Text in Product Page

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_text_area');

function display_text_area()
{

    echo __('FREE LOCAL SHIPPING', 'woocommerce');
}
```

Just Place the codes above in your `functions.php` and you are good to go.

Comment: Hello Kashalo,
Thanks so much for your help. Both solutions work like magic.

Comment: @user10333075 you can add the shortcode  as follow: 

`echo do_shortcode('[block id="free-international-shipping"] ');`

Comment: Hello Kashalo, Thanks so much for your help. I really like the first one. one more request please...=) I would like to replace the message with some shortcodes. Right now, when I replace the texts in your code to my shortcode, for example like [block id="free-international-shipping"], instead of showing what is in the block content, it is showing the shortcode itself. What is the trick to solve this? Again, many thanks for your help!! You're great!! 

J

Comment: @user10333075 you want to put the shorcode as default value right?

Comment: I think yes. So that I can edit the block content instead of the codes directly every time something needs to be changed.

Comment: use the code i wrote in the comment above instead of `echo __('FREE LOCAL SHIPPING', 'woocommerce');`

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. And to add it to `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` as it would be?